# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_13_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 0)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, openai-gym

My code looks like this:

```
lr = 1e-3
window_length = 1
emb_size = 100
look_back = 10

expert_model = Sequential()
expert_model.add(Embedding(num_classes + 1, emb_size, input_length=look_back,mask_zero=True))
expert_model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(look_back,window_length)))
expert_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

All I want is to pass a list of classes of size 10 to an embedding layer and then to an LSTM one to predict the next class to come. Maybe the length of that list is not 10, so I put the `mask_zero` attribute to `True` and the vocabulary of the embedding layer with one extra value. Is this correct?

In addition, I'm not very sure what does the `window_length` means. Does it means the number of sequences to pass to the embedding? When I try to run this I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_13_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 0)
```

To preprocess data I'm using a `Processor` object as this model is for a OpenAI environment called "RecoGym". The class is as follows:

```
class RecoProcessor(Processor):
    def process_observation(self, observation):
        if observation is None:
            return np.array([], dtype='float32')
        return np.array(observation, dtype='float32')

    def process_state_batch(self, batch):
        return np.array(batch).astype('float32')

    def process_reward(self, reward):
        return np.array(reward).astype('float32')

    def process_demo_data(self, demo_data):
        for step in demo_data:
            step[0] = self.process_observation(step[0])
            step[2] = self.process_reward(step[2])
        return demo_data
```

Please, I need some help. If you could only give me a tutorial on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please also post the code you have used for preprocessing your data. There is a shape mismatch happening at preprocessing step.

Comment: @user110327 There you have. It might be a little bit strange, but OpenAI library requires that way. You can find the environment easily looking for RecoGym at Google if you need to.

Comment: Window size is the length of the sequence. For example, if your sequence is "1,2,3.4" then a window size of 2 gives "1,2", "2,3", "3,4". I am sorry I am unable to help you with the actual issue because the input shape is still not clear to me.